# Creating  a user in a LightSwitch application on non authenticated web site

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

How can I add a user to the asp_Users table in my LightSwitch application with non-forms based authentication?

I have an application with forms authentication, and I need another one without any authentication for registration.

I have set up the same application name for both sites.

```
Application type:
Client>Web
Server>IIS
```

If I have both applications with forms authentication everything works OK with this code:

```
Application.Current.User.AddPermissions(Permissions.SecurityAdministration);
var NewUser = this.DataWorkspace.SecurityData.UserRegistrations.AddNew();
NewUser.UserName = "XXXX";
NewUser.FullName = "XXXX XXXX";
NewUser.Password = "*********";
this.DataWorkspace.SecurityData.SaveChanges();

var UserRole = (from role in this.DataWorkspace.SecurityData.Roles
                                where role.Name == "Customer"
                                select role).FirstOrDefault();

if (UserRole != null)
 {
    var newRA = this.DataWorkspace.SecurityData.RoleAssignments.AddNew();
    newRA.Role = UserRole;
    newRA.User = NewUser;
    this.DataWorkspace.SecurityData.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setup a command that directly executes the `aspnet_Membership_CreateUser` stored procedure on the database, obviously passing the required values for all the parameters the stored proc expects.